# How can I find the dual problem to the following convex problem?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems

$\min\{-\sum_{j=1}^n\log{x_j}: q(x)\leq0\};\ q(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^TQx+b^Tx+c $

Where Q is a positive definite matrix, $b\in R^n, c\in R$

So far I have:

$L(x,\lambda) = -\sum_j \log x_j + \lambda(\frac{1}{2}x^TQx+b^Tx+c)$

And, since first I should look for $\inf_{x}\{L(x,\lambda)\}$:

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_j} = -\frac{1}{x_j} + \lambda((x_j\sum_i Q_{ij})+b_j)=0$

How should I proceed to get the dual problem?

Comment: Writing the Lagrangian and taking the partial derivatives of x, but got me nowhere.

Comment: Your derivative with respect to $x_j$ is incorrect. The derivative of $\tfrac{1}{2}x^TQx$ with respect to $x_j$ is $e_j^TQx=\sum_i Q_{ij} x_i$

Comment: I'm actually not sure you're going to get an analytic expression for the dual. There's never a guarantee that you can.